# tf.contrib.ffmpeg.decode_audio verbosity

Tags: tensorflow

When we evaluate the tensor returned by `tensorflow.contrib.ffmpeg.decode_audio()`, the ffmpeg log shows up in the terminal, leading to a flood of messages when decoding a large number of files. Is it possible to disable the verbosity for ffmpeg ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's hard-coded in the contrib op here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/0b437ada0654820e21f81bd415f691251408346a/tensorflow/contrib/ffmpeg/default/ffmpeg_lib.cc#L52

You could modify that and compile TensorFlow from source, send a PR to make it a flag (or an op attribute which gets passed in), or file a feature request.

Comment: Thanks, Allen. Yong Tang [replied on github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14733#issuecomment-346173682) pointing to [an existing PR](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/14582).